# Is there a method to create separate and multiple lists from a single JSON in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Below is my JSON that I have fetched from the server. now I have to create a separate list based on `docgroup`. Suppose there is 2 same *PAN Card* value for `docgroup`. So I have to create a list of `docgroup` which has *PAN Card* as value. So what really I want is, first we have to check to find the similar `docgroup` value and create a list of that.
Thank you in advance.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Upload front side",
    "information": "Should match PAN no. mentioned on IEC copy and self attested",
    "docgroup": "PAN Card",
    "status": "Active",
    "requiredStatus": 0,
    "stage": 1,
    "type": 0,
    "extension": "string",
    "createdBy": 0,
    "createdAt": "2021-06-08 04:46:00.822",
    "lastupdatedBy": 0,
    "lastUpdatedAt": "2021-06-08 04:46:00.822",
    "id": 1,
    "countryId": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Upload back side",
    "information": "Should match PAN no. mentioned on IEC copy and self attested",
    "docgroup": "PAN Card",
    "status": "Active",
    "requiredStatus": 0,
    "stage": 1,
    "type": 0,
    "extension": "string",
    "createdBy": 0,
    "createdAt": "2021-06-08 04:46:00.822",
    "lastupdatedBy": 0,
    "lastUpdatedAt": "2021-06-08 04:46:00.822",
    "id": 2,
    "countryId": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Upload IEC copy",
    "information": "Please upload IEC copy (self attested)",
    "docgroup": "IEC Copy",
    "status": "Active",
    "requiredStatus": 0,
    "stage": 1,
    "type": 0,
    "extension": "string",
    "createdBy": 0,
    "createdAt": "2021-06-08 04:46:00.822",
    "lastupdatedBy": 0,
    "lastUpdatedAt": "2021-06-08 04:46:00.822",
    "id": 3,
    "countryId": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Upload address proof",
    "information": "Please upload latest electricity bill/ telephone bill (any 1)",
    "docgroup": "Office address proof",
    "status": "Active",
    "requiredStatus": 0,
    "stage": 1,
    "type": 0,
    "extension": "string",
    "createdBy": 0,
    "createdAt": "2021-06-08 04:46:00.822",
    "lastupdatedBy": 0,
    "lastUpdatedAt": "2021-06-08 04:46:00.822",
    "id": 4,
    "countryId": 1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `List.where()` to group/filter lists based on some condition.

For your case check this out.

```dart
  List panCardList = jsonList.where((json) => json['docgroup'] == 'PAN Card');
  List otherCardList = jsonList.where((json) => json['docgroup'] != 'PAN Card');
```